# How do I make the mesh more jagged in sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

I'm using pinch, crease, draw and flatten brush to achieve the objective but it still allows some bumpy look. I want to make the mesh have a sharp edge like a square.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used sculpt mode much but I would imagine you might be able to do it using a flatten brush if you turn up the strength but set it to a really small radius. If it doesn't work I apologize for wasting your time.